# Installing kali on android

Tags: kali-linux, android

Its my 6th time trying to install Kali on my Android last errors i capitalized it and fixed it but now It hang up on `configuring netHunter on termux`. I do the same procedure and restart doing all but it gives me this

```
Resolving offs.ec... 67.199.248.13, 67.199.248.12
Connecting to offs.ec|67.199.248.13|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2022-10-19 14:04:48 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: It seems the file that it, whatever it is, tries to access does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that they're gone. The page redirects (for me) to some bitly stuff. That is a domain shortener. So, if this is essential to your installation, you will need to find an updated link.